# Using libsvn(_client) in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, svn

Just out of interest I'm am looking into accessing SVN through objective-c. Now I have found I can use the libsvn library, but I am unable to find any documentation on this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official C API for subversion (latest version - including libsvn_client):

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/

You may also find useful documentation in the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), available online, especially in the ["Using API"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html) section.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific Objective C API but you can just use the C API.

The [subversion web pages](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/) include a listing of the functions and data structures

I found some [examples](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch08.html) in the book Version Control with Subversion by Ben Collins-Sussman, Brian W. Fitzpatrick, C. Michael Pilato